# delphi string to "const buffer"

Tags: string, delphi, constants, buffer

I have a dll which procedure accepts: "const buffer" parameter.

There is also an example of passing value to this parameter:

```
var
str: array [0..200 - 1] of Char;
LTextSend: string;
begin
  LTextSend := 'Text';
  StrLCopy(PChar(@str[0]), PChar(LTextSend), High(str));

  Dll_procedure(str, Length(LTextSend));
end;
```

1. can this parameter be only passed through this declaration: str: array [0..200 - 1] of Char;
2. Isn't there an easier way to pass string (of different length) to this dll parameter?

Thanks

Comment: That 200 seems an arbitrary choice here, the DllProc is accepting strings of var length.

Comment: In order for us to help you, you need to provide 1) the signature of the DLL procedure, 2) the official documentation of the DLL procedure, and 3) your Delphi version (especially before 2009 or 2009+).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the procedure like this:

```
DLL_procedure(str[1], Length(str));
```

This works because Delphi untyped parameters are sent the same way as `var` parameters, they're sent by reference. The compiler will send a pointer to `str[1]`, the first char in the string, but that's actually a pointer to the whole string. As usual, make sure the string actually contains an first character (ie: it's not empty).

Your number 1 problem depends entirely on the DLL. The "signature" allows any length of data to be sent, but that doesn't mean the DLL is prepared for anything. Maybe it can only handle 200 bytes at a time.

Comment: Sorry for my random outbursts in now deleted comments.

Comment: @David, didn't see any of the random outbursts, now you made me curious.

Comment: I was getting uptight about str[1] on an empty string. I guess that provokes range error. But I made a mess of my comments and deleted since you do address the issue anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're making a copy to a temporary buffer.

It does only make sense if the `Dll_procedure` will modify the buffer. But I doubt it will.

So you could simply write:

```
Dll_procedure(Pointer(LTextSend)^, Length(LTextSend));
```

Or a variant making the string unique before the call:

```
Dll_procedure(LTextSend[1], Length(LTextSend));
```